# 5+ items in Google SERPs?

Tags: google-search, search-results

I'm tinkering with a website and the search results page for a certain page it is showing this unexpected *5+ items* thing (see attached image).

Where does this come from? And how to fix it? Or is there no need to fix it?

[image: Photo of SERP entry]

Comment: This most probably comes from implemented [microdata](http://schema.org/docs/schemas.html) on your website.

Comment: Search on your code _5+ items_ to see if you find something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They look like ones which Google automatically generate and will likely stay whilst your page stays the same. See here : http://insidesearch.blogspot.co.uk/2011/08/new-snippets-for-list-pages.html